# What is the |> operator in this example

Tags: ocaml

What does the `|>` operator mean in the following example?

```
open Framework
open Template

let () =
  create_server ()
  |> get "/" (fun req -> h1 ["This is the index page."] |> respond)
  |> get "/:name" (fun req ->
      Printf.sprintf "Hello, %s!" (param req "name") |> respond)
  |> listen 1337
```

The example is taken from this github repo https://github.com/jdan/ocaml-web-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `|>` is the "reverse function application" operator.

In other words, `x |> f` has the same meaning as `f x`.

The operator form is useful for writing a "pipeline" of function applications without requiring parentheses.

```
let f_parenthesized x = int_of_float (abs_float (sin x))

let f_pipelined x = x |> sin |> abs_float |> int_of_float
```

(This function is not very useful, it's just an example.)